# Get value inside unordered list using React UseRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I have the below code, in which I am trying to get the value inside list using when a person clicks on the button wrapped inside that is inside list element. I tried using UseRef but it is returning all the listed items, but In my case I only want to target the value that is associated with that button. Here is my current approach.

```
const tabRef = useRef();

  function addButtonHandler() {
    console.log(tabRef.current.innerText);
  
  }

<ul ref={tabRef}>
    <li >
      <button onClick={addButtonHandler}></button>
      Some context here.</li>
      <li >
      <button onClick={addButtonHandler}"></button>
      More context here.</li>
      <li >
      <button onClick={addButtonHandler}></button>
      even more context here.</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a good candidate for [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). Also, you don't necessarily need a ref here just to get the value, because JavaScript event handlers provide you with the `event` object, which includes the `target` of the event! You could certainly use a ref to store it for later, but my point here is that `useRef` is not a necessary part of getting a value from a list in an event handler. No "Reacty" features needed at all here!

```js
const App = () => {

  function handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
      console.log(event.target.nextSibling);
    }
  }

  return (
  <ul onClick={handleClick}>
    <li>
      <button>Button 1</button>
      <span>Some context here.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button>Button 2</button>
      <span>More context here.</span>
    </li>
    <li >
      <button>Button 3</button>
      <span>even more context here.</span>
    </li>
    </ul>)
    }
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brendan Bond. It is working just fine :)

Comment: @user19958227 glad to hear it. To add a little bit of clarity to my answer - when I say that event handlers provide you with the `event` object, this is not a feature unique to React! All we've done here is use regular old JavaScript APIs to get the value from within a list, we've used zero "special" React features.

Answer (score 0):

You may get DOM nodes of those `<li>`s by looking at `tabRef.current.children[n]`

But not sure if ref is the right way in React to achieve what you wanted to do.
How about to hold the text within an array?

```
const textArr = ['Some context here', 'More context here', 'even more context here'];
const addButtonHandler = (text) => { console.log(text) };
return (<ul>
  { textArr.map(text => 
    <li key={text}><button onClick={() => addButtonHandler(text)} />{text}</li>) }
  </ul>)
```